# Django: How to set a field to NULL?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a field allow NULL value, but how can I set it back to NULL? not blank

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Assign `None`.​

Comment: So simple, but not easily found in the Django docs. They need an FAQ that's searchable by google.

Comment: Does not work for `ManyToManyField`. `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`.

Comment: @Deleet A ManyToManyField is represented in the database as another table, where a relation can exist or not (it will be another row in the m2m table). There is no field to assign NULL to. See the clear or remove keywords to remove all m2m relations. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear